# Problem with testing virtual time with spring-webflux WebClient

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

The test below passes when I use *`monoFromSupplier`* as *`selectedMono`*. 
However, when I switch to *`monoFromWebClient`* it doesn't advance time properly. What am I doing wrong here?

```
StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> {
            Mono<String> monoFromSupplier = Mono.fromSupplier(() -> "AA")
                    .doOnNext(po -> {
                        System.out.println("monoFromSupplier:onNext " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    });

            Mono<String> monoFromWebClient = WebClient.create("http://...")
                    .get()
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class)
                    .doOnNext(po -> {
                        System.out.println("monoFromWebClient:onNext " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    });


            Mono<?> selectedMono = monoFromSupplier; 
            return selectedMono.repeatWhen(companion -> companion.take(3)
                    .delayUntil(r -> {
                        Duration dur = Duration.ofSeconds(500);
                        System.out.println("delay... " + dur);
                        return Mono.delay(dur);
                    }))
                    .last()
                    .log();

        })
                .thenAwait(Duration.ofDays(1))
                .expectNextCount(1)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reactor virtual time support only works within a single JVM - it works by changing the `Scheduler`'s clock (often making it tick faster). `WebClient` here crosses a network boundary and sends a real HTTP request - Reactor can't manipulate the real, physical time.

TL;DR; this is not supported.